# matlab conditional expectation seems not to work for lognormal

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have already tried similar code for other distributions (exponential, normal etc) and in those cases the code works. 
However for the lognormal distribution case there seems to be a problem in the way matlab computes the numerical integral.

The code:

```
function y=condint(sigma,mi,phihat)
y=quad(@phipr,phihat,110,0.000000000000001)

    function y=phipr(x)
      y=1./(1-logncdf(phihat)).*1/(2*pi*sigma^2).^(1/2).*exp(-((log(x)-mi).^2)./(2*sigma^2));
    end
end
```

it fails to have the obvious property that the conditional expected value for higher cutoffs (phihat) should be higher. Is this a generic problem of the numerical procedures for a distribution that decays very fast? Is this a known problem?
Thank you for your help

P.s. In the above I used as upper bound 110, because when using parameters mi=0 and sigma=0.25 using higher values would give wierd results even for the cdf. Again is this related with problems in the trapeziod integral approximation?

Comment: The problem is made worse (more evident) for low values of sigma.

Answer (score 0):

Error in the code:
logncdf(phihat) should be logncdf(phihat,mi,sigma).

That solves it.